# LibGdx how to return from libgdx class to an androidActivity

Tags: android-intent, initialization, libgdx

So, in a libgdx android project we have a folder with android activities and another with source code of the libgdx project.

To start the "game" from an Android activity we use `initialize(new MyGdxGame(),cfg);`

Now i need to know how to return to a android activity like main menu from a libgdx class inside the game...

I try to extend class from Activity to get the `contextApplication`, but i can't fill the 2nd argument, because the program don't recognize the android classes inside libgdx classes...

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to use Android-specific code in an libGDX project is to create a platform-independent interface in the libGDX core project (e.g., `interface PlatformStuff`), then in each platform-specific back end (e.g., desktop or Android) implement that interface with platform specific objects (so `class AndroidPlatformStuff implements PlatformStuff`).  You can pass the platform specific implementation of the interface into the generic code when you construct it (e.g., `new MyGdxGame(new AndroidPlatformStuff())`.

Calling out to Android code that changes activities and context may take a bit more work (because it interacts with the libGDX infrastructure a bit), but should also be doable.  You should be able to use the tutorials for integrating support for advertisements to get the basic idea.  See http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx or http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific

Answer (score 1):

First you should create an interface class in your core folder. This is usually placed with your game class. As an example let's say your function name will be LoginFacebook() for the interface class called ActionResolver

Interface class

```
package com.mygdx.game;

public  interface ActionResolver {
    public void LoginFacebook();

}
```

Now in your game class, you should have the following constructor:

```
public SpaceXplorerGame(ActionResolver actionResolver)
{
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;
}
```

Now in your android folder, in src -> com.mygdx.game.android (your package name), you should create your handler class, in my case called ActionResolverAndroid

```
public class ActionResolverAndroid implements ActionResolver {
    Handler handler;
    Context context;


    public ActionResolverAndroid(Context context) {
        handler = new Handler();
        this.context = context;
    }

public void LoginFacebook()
{
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Now calling the function LoginFacebook() from LibGdx will take you to your LoginAcitivty.class in android.
Hopefully i did not miss anything

Answer (score 0):

you should create call back;
create a interface and implement on android class, then pass this to libgdx and when you need call related method.

Answer (score 0):

The libGDX documentation for advertising platforms uses exactly what you need. It creates an interface in the libGDX core and implements a handler in the android launcher which can be called from the core part.

**See here**: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

Basically skip all the advertising stuff. **Scroll down till "Control" and just implement the following parts:**

- **register a new Handler inside your AndroidLauncher**. This is neccessary so the handler can handle the implemented function of the Interface in the correct android thread later... (see "HelloWorldAndroid")
- **Create an interface in your core project** (like IActivityRequestHandler)
- **Let your AndroidLauncher implement the function and use the handler to perform the actual function within your android thread**

Finally you need to **pass a reference** to your libGDX core code. Personally i used it by implementing a **singleton-class** inside my core project like this:

```
class SingletonData{
  private SingletonData(){
  }
  private static SingletonData instance;
  public static SingletonData getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
      instance = new SingletonData(); // can only be assessed here. no other class can generate a second instance
    }
    return instance;
  } 

  private IActivityRequestHandler handler;

  public void setHandler(IActivityRequestHandler handler){
    this.handler=handler;
  }

  public IActivityRequestHandler getHandler(){
    return this.handler;
  }
}
```

And in your AndroidLauncher (i.e. HelloWorldAndroid) call at the end of it's creation the following to **register it**:

```
SingletonData.getInstance().setHandler(this);
```

Now you can **use it** inside any Core-Class you like by:

```
SingletonData.getInstance().getHandler().showAds(true); // showAds or whatever your interface handler implements
```

PS: make sure to call getHandler() after your game starts, so you don't get a null reference.